# How can I move apps en masse to my SD card?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, motorola-moto-g2

Apps keep getting installed on my internal storage when I would much rather they be on my much larger SD card that is formatted as internal memory. Is there a way to tell my phone to move a bunch of Apps at once?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry its not possible with rooting the device either. As PlayStore firstly download the application to your internal memory without seeing your settings whether you want your application on your internal or external. From that state it can be moved from internal storage to external storage if application permits itself.

You can think it as an restriction posed by Google.

Answer (score 0):

Tutorial :

Note : First Make sure to enable " **Allow Unknown Sources Aplications to install** "

File Manager Link: http://www.apk4fun.com/apk/50967/

1. Download an App called " **Apps Backup & Restore** "
   **Download Link** : http://app-backup-restore.en.uptodown.com/android
   Note : You can download it in Google Play Store

2.. Install the downloaded Aplication (apk) in your device **"App Backup & Restore "**

3. Open the Application
4. Make sure you are in a window called " Installed " , where you can see all your installed applications.
5. Select/Mark all the apps you want to backup and click " Backup" and wait for the process to complete..
6. Go to your Internal Storage Directory using File Manager
7. Search for a folder called " **App Backup & Restore** "
8. Copy/Move this folder to your Sd Card Directory...

**Done**

Answered using LG G3